# Mapbox Map disappears when zooming

Tags: javascript, vue.js, themes, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a strange issue with my Mapbox map.

I implement this map on a Vue.js application :

```
created () {
  // Mapbox example
  // https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/simple-map/
  mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZmNvcmRpbGxvdCIsImEiOiJjaXBiYWgzNWQwMDFjdXRrc281Mnp5cmd6In0.ocQvHwCUWJh_xlfvEBcAVg'
},

mounted () {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'mapbox',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
    })
  })
}
```

The map is correctly displayed. But as soon as I zoom or resize the map disappears completely. All style, markers remain and the names of countries / cities, etc. also.

I saved my screen. The map is already initialized at the beginning of the video: https://share.getcloudapp.com/o0uD68JN

Do you have any idea why this happens?

Best,

Comment: It will be much easier for people to help if you post your site on codepen or somewhere similar.

Comment: Hi @SteveBennett

Apologies but I can't publish any code at this moment...